# Jquery and Django CSRF Token

Tags: jquery, python, django, csrf

I have 2 html Pages.

A Parent Page and a Child Page.  The Child Page Contains a Submit Button that runs code on the Parent Page to submit an Ajax message.

I load the child page using $.load() method and then when the button is clicked it runs a $.ajax .POST Method.  This post method only passes a JSON String to the Python Code.

When I do this on any browser except IE It works fine.  However when I run this code in IE.  I get Python / Django Errors about CSRF Tokens.

I *Think* the reason is because the child page is just a refresh of current page itself with the serverside code being run.

Does anyone know how I should go about getting this to work.

Cheers,

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are not passing the csrf token with **POST**. Try doing what I have done in *data*. That is to fetch the csrf token (or your own method) and pass it in your arguments.

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data : {csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value},
    dataType : "json",
    success: function( data ){
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: This approach is fine, but if you're making many ajax requests, you may find it more convenient to pass the CSRF token as a header instead. For more information see the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: I find `data: {..., 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}, ...` more straightforward.

Comment: or in `.html` template: `<script> var django_csrf_token = '{{ csrf_token }}'; </script>` to be usable from static `.js`.

Answer (score 13):

If you are sending a POST request body it maybe easier to add the csrf token as a request header instead.  I find this approach easier to read, as it does not clutter up the request body with a token. Most AJAX request will send the csrf token as a header as suggested by the Django documentation.

```
function startTest(testId) {
  var payload = JSON.stringify({
    test_id : testId
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "/test-service/",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
    data: payload,
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response.id + " " + response.name);
  }).fail(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/csrf/#ajax) on CSRF and AJAX:

> The CSRF token is also present in the DOM, but only if explicitly included using csrf_token in a template. The cookie contains the canonical token; the CsrfViewMiddleware will prefer the cookie to the token in the DOM. Regardless, you’re guaranteed to have the cookie if the token is present in the DOM, so **you should use the cookie!**

**Example** *(also from the docs)*

> ```
> // using jQuery
> function getCookie(name) {
>     var cookieValue = null;
>     if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
>         var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
>         for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
>             var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
>             // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
>             if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
>                 cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return cookieValue;
> }
>
> var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
> ```

Or any other way of interacting with cookies could be used.