# Javascript POST to Django using Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to send an post request over ajax but the ajax doesn't seem to be firing. In `create_post()`, `console.log("i'm clicked");` does shows up in the console. The print statements in `monthly_query(request)` don't show up in the log.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/create_post/" id="post-form">
<select id = "datasource">
    <option value="data1">data1</option>
    <option value="data2">data2</option>
</select>
<select id="sourceyear">
    {% for year in years %}
    <option value="Years">{{ year }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<select id="sourcemonth">
    <option value="Monthly">1</option>
    <option value="Monthly">2</option>
    <option value="Monthly">3</option>
    <option value="Monthly">4</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="create_post()"/>
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

 $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

function create_post() {
        console.log("i'm clicked");
        $.ajax({
            url: "create_post/",
            cache : "false",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data : { 'source': $("#datasource").val(), 'year': $("#sourceyear").val(), 'month': $("#sourcemonth").val() },

            success : function(json) {
                console.log("my json")
                $("#outgoingvalue").prepend(json.result);   
            },

            error: function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }  
        });
    }
}
```

views.py:

```
def monthly_query(request):
    print("request made")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("post request success")
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns (
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.metrics, name='metrics'),
    url(r'^api/graphs', views.graphs, name='graphs'),
    url(r'^create_post/$', views.monthly_query, name='create_post'),
)
```

EDIT:
Additional javascript:

```
 function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {

        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    function sameOrigin(url) {
        //test that a given url is a same-origin URL
        //url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.local.host;
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;

        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin +'/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if(!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {

                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
```

Edit:
Output of `beforeSend: function(xhr, settings)`
`console.log(settings);`: Object { url: "/create_post/", type: "POST", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true, async: true, contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; …", accepts: Object, contents: Object, responseFields: Object, 14 more… }

Comment: can you manually navigate to it in the browser?

Comment: @Busturdust it's say `views.monthly_query didn't return an HttpResponse object`

Comment: you are printing a string, not returning an HTTPResponse

Comment: @Busturdust I added return HttpResponse(" ") and that didn't make a difference. When you meant navigate to it, you meant /create_post correct?

Comment: you may also need a `status=200` to sy,mbol success. you should reserach more about HTTP communication

Comment: for me i use chrome, open developer console, choose network and check it. what wrong with your request? what url it sent? what response? i think your browser has the same tool

Comment: @Busturdust I updated the OP with more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue - 1

In your ajax request you are requesting `create_post/` which is a relative url. So if you're in `/home/`, the request would be sent to `/home/create_post/`. You should use a path relative to root. So it should be `/create_post`.

#### Issue - 2 & 3

`print` would display the message on your console but it does not send the string as a html response.

And you need to handle the csrf tokens. It's better to pass it as a part of the request or exempt it.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def monthly_query(request):
    print("request made")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse("post request success")
```

You need to return a `HttpResponse` from a view for it to be sent as a response from the server. The `csrf_exempt` decorator will exempt the view from csrf protection.

You can import it like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

Comment: `print("request made")` does not even show up in the log after clicking submit. I made the changes showed in your post.

Comment: Please change your ajax request url to be `/create_post/` - add the beginning slash.

Comment: `console.log(json)` to see what the server returns!

Comment: `function(json)` never gets executed

Comment: Then the error gets called? Either one has to be called. Also check your console logs for possible JS errors.

Comment: Does this part - `console.log("i'm clicked");` fire?

Comment: I edited my original script to include javascript code that was handling the csrf_token. It seem when I remove this piece of code I get a console.log error about a CSRF error. This comes with a 403 error.

Comment: That explains. You need to either pass the CSRF token or exempt that view. Updating my code.

Comment: I know I accepted this answer, but I am curious as to how I could pass the csrf_token as part of the request and validate it. Wouldn't this be more secure than an exemption?

Comment: Yes, that would definitely make it more secure. Please follow this question for more details -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614947/jquery-and-django-csrf-token or if you have any specific questions, please ask a new question. Will try to help!